# Combine multiple styles in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-styles

I would like to ask if it is possible to combine different style formatting in pandas.
For instance I want to combine the following  4 styles at once.

```
df.style.format({'vm_unity': '{:.2%}'}).bar(subset=['vm_unity'], align='mid', color=['#d65f5f', '#5fba7d'])
df.style.bar(subset=['vm_top'], align='mid', color=['#d65f5f', '#5fba7d'])
df.style.bar(subset=['vm_bot'], align='mid', color=['#d65f5f', '#5fba7d'])
df.style.bar(subset=['Sy'], align='mid', color=['#d65f5f', '#5fba7d'])
```

The way that I currently perform it is to combine them in a single line but I believe that it's not the most elegant way of doing it

```
df.style.format({'vm_unity': '{:.2%}'}).bar(subset=['vm_unity'], align='mid', color=['#d65f5f', '#5fba7d']).bar(subset=['vm_top'], align='mid', color=['#d65f5f', '#5fba7d']).bar(subset=['vm_bot'], align='mid', color=['#d65f5f', '#5fba7d']).bar(subset=['Sy'], align='mid', color=['#d65f5f', '#5fba7d'])
```

Can you please drop a line for a more effective way?

Comment: I don't have an answer to this, but I think the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) would guide that the former approach is *much* preferred (in lieu of a more concise approach perhaps posed here).

Comment: I've already posted an answer down below, but may I ask what you mean with 'more effective way'? Because I think that your way is already good and readable enough.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the python's native linebreak \ and break the line afterwards. Your code would be:

```
df.style.format({'vm_unity': '{:.2%}'})\
        .bar(subset=['vm_unity'], align='mid', color=['#d65f5f', '#5fba7d'])\
        .bar(subset=['vm_top'], align='mid', color=['#d65f5f', '#5fba7d'])\
        .bar(subset=['vm_bot'], align='mid', color=['#d65f5f', '#5fba7d'])\
        .bar(subset=['Sy'], align='mid', color=['#d65f5f', '#5fba7d'])
```

Answer (score 2):

### 1st Method

So there are multiple ways to use/apply multiple styles to a Styler/pandas dataframe. For me, the easiest and most straightforward way is  to export styles, and that works as the following

```py
myStyle = myStyler.export()
```

and in your case that's

```
style_1 = bar(subset=['vm_top'], align='mid', color=['#d65f5f', '#5fba7d']).export()
```

This will return a style object that you can then later apply using

```
from pandas.io.formats.style import Styler
Styler.use([style_1])
```

Cool thing about this function is that you can use either on or several different styles at once, by passing a list of styles. Therefore, to answer your question, just make sure that you export all styles that you want in advance, and then you can apply all at once.

### 2nd Method

is by using `pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.where`, in case you're interested in applying only two alternative styles.