# Adding background-color to column names and cells based on condition

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

Is it possible to add background color to column names while also changing cell background colors based on a separate condition?

I'm currently able to highlight cells based on a condition, but unsure how to add background color to column names:

```
# create dataframe 
import pandas as pd

data = {'Cuisine':['Italian','Indian','Nepalese','Mexican', 'Thai'],
   'Geographic Location':['Europe','Asia','Asia','N.America','Asia']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data) print(df)

    Cuisine Geographic Location
0   Italian              Europe
1    Indian                Asia
2  Nepalese                Asia
3   Mexican           N.America
4      Thai                Asia


# highlight cells based on condition
def highlight_Asia(x):
    return ['background-color: GreenYellow' if v =='Asia' else '' for v in x]

df.style.apply(highlight_Asia)
```

[image: cells highlighted based on cond.]

```
# highlight column names
def highlight_header(x):
    y= ['background-color: LightSkyBlue' for v in list(x)]
    return y

df.style.apply(highlight_header)
```

[image: cant figure out how to highlight column names]

## Desired outcome:

[image: desired outcome]

References: 
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49954454/dataframe-styling-based-on-conditions-for-groups-of-columns)
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44049405/combine-multiple-styles-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **applymap(mapperFunc, subset=[ColOfInterest])** on your pandas style object, it will call the mapperFunc for each value in the pandas dataframe with the values passed, optionally you can pass selective columns using subset parameter.

### Example code:

```
def color_me(percentage):
  color = 'green'
  if percentage < 40:
    color = 'red'

  return 'background-color: %s' % color

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Marks' : range(0,101,20)})
df.style.applymap(color_me)
```

### Output

[image]